# How does a USB requestWait react to an NAK from a slave device?

Tags: android, usb

I am trying to get an Android USB host program to connect to a slave which is effectively a USB-serial converter. The slave device is set up currently to return NAK when there is no data available, and I am polling the slave to see if there is any IN data by using queue() and requestWait() on the IN endpoint as part of an onAnimationUpdate listener. However the system is getting stuck in the requestWait() - presumably waiting till it gets a definitive reply to the queued request.
I would have thought that a NAK would be taken as an indication that the slave has reacted to the request and a null result or similar passed back.  However, I can find no detailed documentation on this.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for advice?

Answer (score 1):

I have sort of resolved this issue - but not very satisfactorily.
It seems that the Android requestWait() function does not recognise a NAK response to an IN as indicating "no data is available" (I would have thought it would return a null since that what the correct result would be) but simply sits and waits until there IS some data available - locking up the system.
I have "solved" this by returning a "NULL" message from my device consisting of a 1-byte reply with ASCII NAK as the single byte.  This works, as I am using ASCII for the message coding.